# Duplicate columns when pandas dataframes are merged

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge df1 and df2. The current problem I am having when I merge df1 and df2 is that it produces duplicate 'Fluc' columns. The dataframes have to be merged `on='Horse'`.

Code for dataframes:

```
cols1 = ['Race', 'Horse', 'Fluc 1', 'Fluc 2','Bookmaker', 'Odds']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols1)
cols2 = ['Race', 'Horse', 'Fluc 1', 'Fluc 2', 'Bookmaker', 'AvgOdds']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols2)
df3 = df2.groupby(by='Horse', sort=False).mean()
df3 = df3.reset_index()
df4 = round(df3,2)
dfmerge = pd.merge(df1,df4,on='Horse',how='inner')
```

Output of df1:

```
              Race           Horse  Fluc 1  Fluc 2      Bookmaker   Odds
0       Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22        BetEasy   4.20
1       Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22           Neds   4.20
2       Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22      Sportsbet   4.20
3       Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22  SportsBetting   4.45
4       Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22         Bet365   4.20
```

Output of df4:

```
              Race           Horse  Fluc 1  Fluc 2      Bookmaker  AvgOdds
0       Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22        BetEasy     4.20
1       Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22           Neds     4.20
2       Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22      Sportsbet     4.20
3       Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22  SportsBetting     4.45
4       Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22         Bet365     4.20
```

Output of dfmerge:

```
              Race           Horse  Fluc 1_x  Fluc 2_x      Bookmaker  Odds  Fluc 1_y  Fluc 2_y  AvgOdds
0       Ipswich R1  Battle Through      8.34      8.38           Neds   8.5      8.34      8.38     8.65
1       Ipswich R1  Battle Through      8.34      8.38      Sportsbet   8.0      8.34      8.38     8.65
2       Ipswich R1  Battle Through      8.34      8.38  SportsBetting   9.1      8.34      8.38     8.65
3       Ipswich R1  Battle Through      8.34      8.38         Bet365   9.0      8.34      8.38     8.65
4       Ipswich R1      Simply Fly      1.89      1.87           Neds   1.8      1.89      1.87     1.84
```

Desired output of dfmerge:

```
              Race           Horse  Fluc 1  Fluc 2      Bookmaker   Odds    AvgOdds
0       Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22        BetEasy   4.20    4.2
1       Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22           Neds   4.20    4.2
2       Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22      Sportsbet   4.20    4.2
3       Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22  SportsBetting   4.45    4.2
4       Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22         Bet365   4.20    4.2
```

Comment: Use [`suffixes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) parameter to suffix the duplicate columns & drop columns based on suffix

Comment: Hi, as you are merging df1 and df4, you should show us the output of df4 instead of df2.  It's the usual behavior of the merge function to add suffixes (_x and _y) to columns that are in both dataframes.

Comment: Why does it not provide an (_x and _y) column for 'Bookmaker', 'Horse', etc. then

Comment: Are you just trying to bring in the AvgOdds column in from df2 into df1? If this is the case, have you tried: how = 'left'?

Comment: I need to merge the Fluc columns so there are no duplicates. This is the main issue

Comment: Duplicate columns is the default behavior. In my environment, the output is in the form of DF4 columns added to the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
dfmerge = pd.merge(df1, df4, on=['Race', 'Horse', 'Fluc 1', 'Fluc 2', 'Bookmaker'], how='inner')
print(dfmerge)
```

**Output:**

```
         Race           Horse  Fluc 1  Fluc 2      Bookmaker  Odds  AvgOdds
0  Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22        BetEasy  4.20     4.20
1  Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22           Neds  4.20     4.20
2  Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22      Sportsbet  4.20     4.20
3  Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22  SportsBetting  4.45     4.45
4  Ipswich R1  Battle Through     4.2    4.22         Bet365  4.20     4.20
```